# how to stop a formula of a cell when we input data in another cell

Tags: excel

I am using a formula in a cell for calculating the days taken for reviewing a document. When I return the document I am filling in the date in another cell. At this juncture I want the formula cell to stop calculating. How can I do so?

E.g. I have 7 columns; when I receive a document I will fill columns A1 and B1 (A1 with the number and B1 with the date), and I will also fill columns C1 and D1 (with my reference number and the date respectively). In column E1 I have given the formula `D1-today()` for calculating the exact number of days the document was with us. When I fill data in G1 and H1, the formula in E1 should stop working.

Answer (score 0):

Use an IF function. IF takes a statement which resolves into a 'boolean value' [ie: 5>4 = TRUE; 5<2 = FALSE], and if the result of that statement is TRUE, it returns one result, and if the result is FALSE, it returns a different result. In your case this is as simple as:

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(G1),ISBLANK(H1)),D1-TODAY(),"")
```

Note that I've used 2 other functions. ISBLANK looks at a cell - if that cell is blank (no formula inside, no data at all), it returns TRUE. Otherwise it returns FALSE. OR works by looking at a number of different 'boolean values'. If any of those boolean values is TRUE, then OR returns TRUE.

So in my example above, if either G1 or H1 is blank, then E1 will result in D1-TODAY(). If neither is blank, E1 will result in "" [which is an empty space].

Note that you could likely simplify this as follows:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(H1),D1-TODAY(),"")
```

Here, it assumes that you will naturally be filling data from left to right - so by the time H1 is not blank, then G1 will also be not blank.